# Не получается слинковать скомпилированный код на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, компиляция, линковка

Есть простая программа на ассемблере (синтаксических ошибок нет). Компилится в obj более-менее нормально, через один раз. Я использую nasm, но когда пытаюсь слинковать через golink — он отказывается работать и выдаёт ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке сохранить текст программы в других различных кодировках (включая UTF-8 и остальные UTF-16) уже отказывается работать компилятор. Он просто не может прочитать текст. Иногда может, но его смущают некоторые символы и он выплёвывает ошибку undefined, конечно же, ничего не скомпилировав.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я обращаюсь к вам за помощью здесь, потому что уже потратил несколько часов на попытки разобраться в этом с использованием информации в интернете. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему с линковкой, или хотя бы посоветуйте, где можно скачать работающий линковщик.

---

Скомпилировал с другими параметрами, теперь линковщик ругается на отсутствие секций...я не понимаю, что происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кодировка текста тут ни при чем. Ошибка говорит что у вас объектный файл формата OMF, и golink не поддерживает такой формат. Нужно или разобраться как с помощью nasm получить объектный файл формата COFF (или MS COFF), или найти конвертер между этими форматами.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться) А то я себе уже голову всю забил этим)

Comment: Разобрался с компилятором под win32 (просто в параметрах вызова nasm вместо просто -f указа -fwin32). Написал в теме.

Comment: `теперь линковщик ругается на отсутствие секций` - возможно в исходном файле нет секций

Comment: В том и дело, что есть) Я взял простенькую программу (код не мой, из интернета), чтобы как раз проверить компиляцию.
https://yadi.sk/d/u46fDiU1Y984CA

Comment: Добавьте код в сам вопрос + как пытались скомпилировать.